# File dialogue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my project I'm doing an asp.net file where I have to upload an image inside a picture box. since I'm new to asp.net dint find any controls related to picture box.

the thing that I have to do is have to use a picture box and when I click on the picture box(or a link button) I have to open a open file dialog box and have to select a respective image from my system. and load it into the picture box.

Is there a way to do that?

so far I'm clear with this code

`<input type="file" name="filediag" style="display:none" />`

`<input type="button" value="browse..." onclick="document.form1.filediag.click()" />`

but this code doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: Question is unclear with lot of spelling and grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using this code below in the code behind page:

HTML code in .aspx page:

```
    <INPUT class=BOX id=File1 type=file name=File1 runat="server"><asp:button id=btnUpload Runat="server" Text="Upload"></asp:button>
```

CODE in cs file:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
 string strName1 = File1.PostedFile.FileName; }
```

This code will get you started.  All you have to do then is save the image to your server and then load the url of the file you saved into the picturebox.

You are trying to use client side code while this is server side code.

Comment: Can you be more specific about saving the image to the server. i want to pass the image/picture dynamically to the picturebox from the asp page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this using javascript:

check out this demo where I did the same: http://upload-at-click.narod.ru/demo2.html